# How to swap days of week in an arraylist

Tags: java

for example, sunday is 1 and monday is 2 , so I want monday as 1 and sunday as 7. It should return the number as string.

Here is something which I tried:

```
public static ArrayList<Respondent2010> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<Respondent2010>();
Map<String, Integer> dm = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); dm.replace("2", 1);
dm.replace("3", 2);
dm.replace("4", 3);
dm.replace("5", 4);
dm.replace("6", 5);
dm.replace("7", 6);
dm.replace("1", 7);
String str = dm.toString();
```

Comment: I don't see arraylist in code.

Comment: Any ways, is this not a matter of iteratting and incrementing by one?

Comment: Now there is an arraylist, but it doesn't seem relevant at all. A Map#replace doesn't do anything if the key doesn't exist, which they don't in your example. Also where is Saturday, Sunday, Monday, etc?

Comment: @matt I want to change from numbers to numbers. it actually starts from sunday that is 1 till saturday that is 7. So instead of sunday as 1, I want monday(i.e. 2) as 1 and so on and sunday as the last(i.e. 7) .

Comment: @beginner you need to add Monday "2" as a key first and after swap with Sunday cause just now you have only six entities. Maybe you should construct map in a correct way from the beginning, depends how you populate your map. Maybe there is efficient way to fill map with key:values

Comment: Don't use Map#replace use Map#put. Also your map should probably be Map<Integer, String>.

Answer (score 0):

Ill answer building from the ops code. First the days of the week are integers.

```
final static int SUNDAY = 1;
final static int MONDAY = 2;
...
```

Then we want the days to map to a different number/ string representation.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then we put the mapping values.

```
map.put(SUNDAY, "7");
map.put(MONDAY, "1");
```

Of course this can be done better using an Enum, but I digress.

Comment: Is there another way other than using map to solve this problem

Comment: @beginner absolutely. You have a map in your initial question. I built on that.